# Unable to set permissions on Exchange 2010 Public Folder

Tags: exchange-2010, public-folders

I've got a client using their public folders to share out some information relating to specific job functions. Currently all the folders are on the top level of the public folder tree and we'd like to consolidate the folders into specific categories so we don't have half a dozen folders at the top level for each job. I've been able to consolidate pretty much all of them down with the exception of two. No one can seem to do anything with either of these folders other than access the information stored in them. I can't even see the properties or change permissions on the folders.

Current system setup is a Exchange 2010 SP3 (No roll ups installed) running on Server 2012 Standard.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

After some additional troubleshooting I found that the folders had been created by multiple employees that were no longer with the organization. The user accounts had been removed but had lingering AD entries identified by "Unknown User-IDSTRING" entries on various objects. Before cleaning up active directory I was unable to run the powershell script AddUsersToPFRecursive.ps1. I'd get access denied errors. After cleaning up AD the script ran successfully.